# MYSQL: what is file directory should be used while using loading csv file?

Tags: mysql

I have a script for loading csv file from D:\ drive which is working really amazing. but however I am getting error when I tried doing same way loading csv file from network drive path and tried googling but  not figured out.

And also I did following changes to my.ini file which is in following path xxx\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

```
secure-file-priv=""
local_infile = 1
```

**First code:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '\\\\12.123.12.12\\General\\Viswanath\\test.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_import_temp
```

**First Error:**
Error Code: 29. File '\12.123.12.12\General\Viswanath\Consolidated Conduent MOM-Q1 - 10-July-2020.csv' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

**Second Code:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '\\\\12.123.12.12\\General\\Viswanath\\test.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_import_temp
```

**Second Error:**
Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

This server is in windows operating system and MySQL version is Server 8.0.

as of now I testing this in MySQL workbench, once it is successfully loaded then I will migrate same code into GUI  so that use can load data from any folder.

Inputs are appreciated.. thank you!!

Comment: Have you restarted MySQL service?

Comment: I did restart MySQL services by going into 'services.msc'.